# Spring-batch-admin-manager 1.3.1.RELEASE : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Our Application is using Spring-batch-admin-manager 1.3.1.RELEASE as a dependency, and some old jackson's dependencies have been excluded (like jackson-mapper-asl) to add new ones (the ones that comes from fasterxml instead of codehaus). New ones from com.fasterxml.* are under version 2.9.8

Problem:

spring-batch-admin-manager-1.3.1.RELEASE-sources.jar!/META-INF/spring/batch/servlet/manager/controller-context.xml contains a bean pointing to older Jackson version, like this:

```
<bean id="objectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"/>
```

It should be override. I tried doing something like this:

> /my-project/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/batch/override/some_name_here.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/batch/servlet/manager/controller-context.xml" />
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="objectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" />
</beans>
```

But I'm still getting the same issue:

```
 SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.admin.web.StepExecutionController#0': Failed to introspect bean class [org.springframework.batch.admin.web.StepExecutionController] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267 undefined)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122 undefined)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096 undefined)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511 undefined)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481 undefined)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312 undefined)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230 undefined)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308 undefined)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197 undefined)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756 undefined)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867 undefined)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542 undefined)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443 undefined)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325 undefined)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107 undefined)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5197 undefined)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5720 undefined)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145 undefined)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707 undefined)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697 undefined)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266 undefined)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149 undefined)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624 undefined)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748 undefined)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701 undefined)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975 undefined)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:612 undefined)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:523 undefined)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:509 undefined)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:245 undefined)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381 undefined)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424 undefined)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338 undefined)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357 undefined)
    ... 30 more
```

How should I deal with this issue?

Comment: Indeed, the object mapper is defined here: https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-batch-admin/blob/9ba22c69128ca344e584256d52455f2ba11c6adb/spring-batch-admin-manager/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/batch/servlet/manager/controller-context.xml#L28. I don't see how you would solve your issue without downgrading jackson version to the one required by Spring Batch Admin. FYI, SBA is deprecated as of Dec 31, 2017 in favor of Spring Cloud Data Flow. You can find a migration guide here: https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Comment: I understand it might not be possible. But we should be able to override that controller-context.xml and the objectMapper bean. I see it says in the logs the value was overridden, but somehow I (maybe because the way contexts are being loaded)  that objectMapper overriding it's not taken in consideration. I would like to give it a try, and fail eventually.  
This is a legacy application, we for sure are thinking in Spring Cloud Data Flow (we in fact are moving  Spring XD to SCDF) but on the meantime we need to fix some security issues in this legacy app (i.e upgrading some dependencies)